# Store Ajax response to display to other users

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching

Some guys made an API which display some Battlefield stats, and requested people to not call the API for every visit to the site, but cache the response and make real calls on a defined interval.

How do I approach this? How can I store data to other users in the frontend?

Comment: You'll need to cache the data on your server to make this accessible to other users. What server-side language are you using?

Comment: What server side language are you using? I'd make a cron job to call the real data and put it into a database, then all the client calls would be to the database on your end.

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or jquery.

Comment: @d_inevitable can you rule out that ajax would be used to make the request to the server for the update? I believe it's part of it, but not the whole piece. That being said, your comment was not only *wrong* on-the-hole, but also came off brash and 'know-it-all-y'.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, if ajax was used it would be almost impossible to cache it, right? You could only cache it in the browser or forward it to the server. The latter would be highly inefficient and complicated, while the former would not quite meet the requirement "to not call the API for every visit to the site" (every new visitor would hit the API). So unless he is using something like node.js has nothing to do with javascript. If he is using node.js he should tag it as such.

Comment: @d_inevitable the server gets the data, caches it. The client can still have an AJAX request going to the server to get the cached data at a set interval.

Comment: @sachleen no doubt about that, but what does that have to do with the topic of this question?

Comment: @d_inevitable I'm not saying you're wrong. OP obviously does not know how to approach the problem. I think Ohgodwhy's issue with your comment was that it simply was not constructive.

Comment: @sachleen yeah I know. Well in my defense I was not trying to be 'unconstructive'. The question is very vague and I tried to make conclusions on the very little info provided and share them. If I was 100% sure there's no ajax I could simply retag the question, but I chose to discuss it instead. I think my logic about this not being js related is very plausible. Also the OP seems to have a tunnel view about trying to find a solution in JS. I think that tunnel must be destroyed.

Comment: @d_inevitable well, I don't disagree with that.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield make that an answer... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What server side language are you using? I'd make a cron job to call the real data and put it into a database, then all the client calls would be to the database on your end.